# PDFParser (TCPdf) connection reset

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I'm using `PDFParser` by Smalot

Some of my PDF's can be converted without any issues using `PDF2Text`. Unfortunately it often returns empty content or no line breaks for example. While the demo of `PDFParser` from Smalot converts all my pdf's without any problem. After installig with composer when using it I get a Connection Reset (`ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`).

I've tried `set_time_limit` to increase my execution time and setting the memory limit up to 1024M, but both had no success.
Calling my php from the command line works fine.

I've also tried to convert these pdf's on http://pdfparser.org/demo and here they get converted without any problem.

I'm not doing anything special in my index file.
Here's the content if it is in anyway useful

```
// Include Composer autoloader if not already done.
include 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Parse pdf file and build necessary objects.
$parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
$pdf    = $parser->parseFile('test.pdf');

$text = $pdf->getText();
echo $text;
```

Comment: Did you have any luck solving this? I'm faced with the same problem

Comment: @GDP Unfortunately not. Apparently it's due to Adobe using a specific content layout or whatever which is not decryptable to text(easily at least), but that way they can make the files smaller and it's still able to convert to a pdf layout or something.